# how to tell the system NOT to do a cleanup when the cell is off screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

Is it possible to tell the iOS system not to set some property's value to default value when the cell scrolls of the screen? It does that automatically at random times. At runtime I set the property, than the cell goes of the screen, system sets the property to default, and I can't use it anymore.. What needs to be done to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: You can avoid cell reuse by giving each cell a unique reuse identifier, but it is much better to simply restore the cell content when required in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Well, you can avoid the _reuse_. You can't avoid cells being thrown away at random times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't even try.

Cells are objects that are only used to display things on the screen. They are not supposed to store any permanent information, they are supposed to be used for different rows of your table at any time.

Find a different place to store your information.

As a general rule, work with the rules of iOS. If you try to work against them, you will never succeed and just waste your time.